# Comparing values in a dynamic sequence

Tags: delphi, compare

I have a logic problem where I need to let the user configure the sequence of which to compare some simple values.

For example, in the INI file, the sequence is stored like:

```
[Fruit]
Apples=0
Oranges=3
Banana=4
Melon=1
Berry=5
Lemon=2
```

In this case, the INI ident is going to be holding a quantity value. The INI value is representing the order of which to compare. So, I need to compare like this:

```
{first}
if CurrentApples > PrevApples
    continue...
    {second}
    if CurrentMelons > PrevMelons
        continue...
        {third}
        if CurrentLemons > PrevLemons
            continue...
            {forth}
            if CurrentOranges > PrevOranges
                continue...etc.
```

If the sequence was changed to be put the Berry comparison first, during runtime I need to be able to compare these quantities in that order. Basically the order at which the comparisons matter and will result in various actions. I cannot dynamically create some variables in a function and just assign them a name.

I was trying to do something with this:

```
var
  TestArray : array[0..5] of Boolean;
begin
  TestArray[0] := CurrentApples > PrevApples;
  TestArray[1] := CurrentMelons > PrevMelons;
  TestArray[2] := CurrentLemons > PrevLemons;
  TestArray[3] := CurrentOranges > PrevOranges;
  TestArray[4] := CurrentBanana > PrevBanana;
  TestArray[5] := CurrentBerry > PrevBerry;
```

And then evaluate the array index in a specific order, but I can't figure out how to do it from the INI values.

Is there some simpler way to do this? If the correct way is just writing hundreds of nested if statements, then I can try to do that, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: Until you can start using arrays and/or dictionaries instead of individual variables, you will be condemned to writing all the combinations by hand. So step 1 is to learn about arrays/dictionaries and containers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IniFile.ReadSection to read key names into a stringlist. They should be saved in same order as they are stored in INI file. 
You then use this as control mechanizm to determine which order to use.

Also you might wanna use TMemIniFile instead of TIniFile as TMemIniFile stores entire ini file into memory. This could come verry usefull when you are reading the values from INI file ofthen becouse regular TIniFile always reads them from the hard drive which could lower the performance.